# Using a JQuery $.each Operator Within a ui.bootstrap Angular Modal To Apply CSS to Each Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal pop up when a certain item is clicked which displays certain numbers and I would like these numbers to change color depending on what their number is (i.e. a low score will be red and a high score will be green).

HTML

```
<html ng-app="root">
    <div class="movie-display-section" ng-controller="movieThumbnailController">
        <a href class="movie-thumbnail" ng-repeat="movie in movies" ng-click="show(movie)">
            <img class="movie-thumbnail-image" src="{{movie.img_src}}">
            <div class="movie-thumbnail-desc">
                <h1>{{movie.name}}</h1>
                <h2>({{movie.year}})</h2>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="movie_modal.html">
        <div class="movie-modal">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <img class="movie-thumbnail-image" src="{{movie.img_src}}">
                <div class="movie-review" ng-repeat="review in reviews">
                    <h2 class="movie-review-user">{{review.user}}</h2>
                    <h1 class="movie-review-rating" ng-class="movieRatingClass">{{review.rating}}</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </script>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
var movies = []; //An array of movies with reviews in them
var root = angular.module('root', ['ui.bootstrap']);

root.controller("modalController", function($scope, $modalInstance, movie){
    $scope.movie = movie;
    $scope.reviews = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        $scope.reviews[i] = reviews[movie.reviews[i]];
    };
    $scope.close = function() {
        $modalInstance.close();
    };
});

root.controller("movieThumbnailController", function($scope, $timeout, $modal, $log){
    $scope.movies = movies;
    $scope.show = function(_movie){
        console.log(_movie.name);
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            controller: "modalController",
            templateUrl: "movie_modal.html",
            windowClass: "movie-modal",
            size: "lg",
            resolve: {
                movie: function() {
                    return _movie;
                }
            } 
        });
    };
});
```

What shows up is a modal with the user's name and their rating as I expected (with some added CSS to prettify it). My questions is, is there a way I can change the style of the rating color inside the JavaScript file, either using JQuery or the Angular library/framework? Let's assume I have the rateColor function that returns a string that is the 6 character color code preceded by "#" (e.g. "#1D3D45")

```
var rateColor = function(rating) {
    //return color string id;
}
```

I know there is the $.each operator in JQuery which I could use to apply it to every "movie-review-rating" class but that doesn't work (I think because the modal is within a script and won't work that way but I may be wrong).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope, $timeout) {
$scope.rating=5;
$scope.rating1=4;
$scope.rateColor = function(rating) {
if(rating==5)
   return "background-color:"+"red";
else
  return "background-color:"+"green"
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<h2 style="{{rateColor(rating)}}">
{{rating}}
</h2>
 <h3 style="{{rateColor(rating1)}}">
{{rating1}}
</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Holy crap, thank you so much. That works beautifully!